Display accounts in report grouped by opening year, showing each until closure
I would like to create a report that displays all accounts grouped by their shop opening year and continues to show each account in subsequent years until the shop closes, without inserting new/duplicate accounts.
I have a Shop Opened and Shop Closed Date fields.
Is it possible to achieve this with a report? Can anyone help me with this scenario?

In general, a report only shows each base record once. That means that a report grouped by open and close dates would show accounts that opened in the same month, and then ordered by their close dates. You'd have to have something else attached to each account in order to have them appear in each of the appropriate rows. For example, you might have a child object that keeps track of each year the account was in an open status, which you might automate through Flows or triggers. At that point, you could use this hypothetical "year of operation" record to show every year the account was open. Note that this design will consume significant storage space in your org. You may want to just consider something more custom, like a Visualforce Page or Lightning Component to display this kind of content.
